# Expo OTA Updates: Update version in app.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

When OTA updating an Expo iOS app that has been distributed to the App Store, can the version number in `app.json` be changed/incremented?

My app shows the `app.json` version number in the Settings screen of my app. If `app.json` cannot be edited for an OTA update, and hence the version number in Settings screen is unchanged by the OTA update, is there another way to check that the OTA update has been successful?

*Using Expo SDK 34, `expo-cli@3.0.9`*

Answer (score 1):

You can tell by using this.

`Constants.nativeAppVersion` or `Constants.nativeBuildVersion`

- The `Info.plist` value for `CFBundleShortVersionString` on `iOS` and
  the `version` name set by version in `app.json` on `Android` at the
  time the `native app` was built.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we manually increment `expo.ios.buildNumber` in `app.json` when we release a new OTA update, which will affects `CFBundleVersion` that is returned by `Constants.nativeBuildVersion`?

Comment: Instead of manually incrementing `expo.version` in `app.json` which affects `CFBundleShortVersionString` returned by `Constants.nativeAppVersion`? And that we only manually increment `expo.version` when we are submitting a new build to the app store?

Comment: This will tell you which version of the app you updated.